# What will happen to the roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ if the $a \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, roots, quadratics

### Exercise:

> What will happen to the roots of the quadratic equation
>   $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
>   if the coefficient $a$ approaches zero while the coefficients $b$ and $c$ are constant, and $b \neq 0$?

---

### Attempt:

$\lim\limits_{a \to 0}{(ax^2 + bx + c)} = bx + c = 0 \longrightarrow x = -\frac{c}{b}$

However, I don't think my solution is complete; shouldn't I end up with $2$ roots? (I've only found $1$.)

---

### Request:

**Is there indeed another root to find? If so, how to I find it?**

Comment: You can't take limits the way you have...$x$ depends on $a$ in a non-trivial way.  Hint: Have you looked at it numerically?  Try, say $ax^2+2x+1=0$ for small $a$...I think the picture becomes clear.

Comment: Think about it graphically. As $a\rightarrow 0 $, the parabola will straighten out into a line. As $a\rightarrow 0$ one zero will approach $\frac{-c}{b}$ and the other zero will approach positive or negative $\infty$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_perturbation#Algebraic_equations

Comment: As a goes to zero your quadratic becomes a line, and there is only one real root..  But you really should discuss what is happening to that other root...it is going of to infinity or - infinity depending on whether a approaches 0 from the left or the right.

Comment: @lulu -- _I'm not sure whether I'm thinking what you're thinking, but..._ According to the quadratic formula $a$ is in the denominator, so when it's small, the result is big. However, I can't get a definite limit here because if I approach negatively or positively (as DougM mentions) I get different results.

Comment: well, looking at the expression given by the quadratic formula...for one root, it is certainly true that the denominator goes to $0$ while the numerator approaches $-2b$.  But for the other root, both numerator and denominator go to $0$.

Comment: You may want to discuss how the limits differ as $a$ approaches zero from above or from below, rather than attempting to find a two-sided limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quadratic equation $ax^x+bx+c=0$ has two roots, $x_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.
We can investigate their behavior when $a \to 0$ by calculating their limits. We assume $b>0$ (we can always mupltiply the equation by -1):
\begin{split}
\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=&\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}  \cdot\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b} \\
= & \lim_{a\to 0}\frac{b^2-4ac-b^2}{2a(\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b)} \\
= & \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{-4ac}{2a(\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b)} \\
= & \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{-4c}{2(\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b)} \\
= & -\frac{c}{b}, \\
\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=&\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{-2b}{2a}  \\
= &\lim_{a\to 0}\left( -\frac{b}{a}\right).
\end{split}
The last expression doesn't only depend on the sign of $b$ but also on the sign of $a$, i.e. the direction from which we're approaching zero, so the limit does not exist. The one-sided limits are equal to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: (regarding the last statement) Doesn't the sign also depend on the sign of $a$? So, that means the limit is undefined since both one-sided limits approach different values.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: 1) Both your limits assume that $b>0$ but that was not stated. You should state that your given limits assume that, and if $b<0$ the two limits are swapped. 2) In your second limit, you say "The one-sided limits [exist]" but one limit is $+\infty$ while the other is $-\infty$. Many would not consider those limits to exist: the text I teach from takes that approach.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why $b$ has to be positive. At first I though I must have made a mistake by canceling square root and square and not including the absolute value, but now I can't find the mistake...

Comment: I got it, ignore the last comment. Gonna edit it....

Comment: Great answer! Definitely the right way to handle the limits.

Answer (score 3):

According to Vieta's formulas

$$x_{1}+x_{2}=-{\frac {b}{a}},\quad x_{1}x_{2}={\frac {c}{a}},$$
for the roots $x_1,x_2$. When $a$ approaches zero, both these quantities become infinite.

For a small $a$ your polinomial will be very small near the point $x = -\frac{b}c$, so one root would be around there. The other will tend to infinity according to Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The roots are $f(a)=x_1=^{{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\over{2a}}=$ and =$g(a)=x_2=^{{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\over{2a}}$. If the limit of $a$ is $0$ and $b>0 $, the limit of $g(a)$ is $-\infty$ if $a$ converges towards $0^+$ and is $+\infty$ if $a$ converges towards $0^-$. $f(a)$ is not determined, so you can apply Hospital and the limit is $-{c\over b}$.   If $<0$ you obtain a similar result mutatis mutandis.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to look at the equation as
$$ ax^2 = -bx-c $$
Then the right-hand side is the same linear function as $a$ varies.
The *left* side is a parabola with apex $(0,0)$ that flattens out towards the $x$-axis as $a$ approaches $0$. What happens to the roots depends on $b$ and $c$:

If $b=0$, then the two roots diverge towards $\pm\infty$, one in each direction.

(In the degenerate case $b=c=0$, the double root at $x=0$ stays put as long as $a$ is nonzero, of course).

Otherwise, *one* of the roots will converge towards the $x$-intercept of of the line, and the *other* one diverges towards $\pm\infty$, with sign depending on whether $a$ approaches $0$ from above or below.

Answer (score 1):

If $a = 0$ then $ax^2 + bx + c = bx + c$ and the equation $bx +c=0$ is a linear equation with a single root;$x = -\frac cb$.

The set of equations $\alpha x^2 + bx^2 + c = 0$ will each have two roots of $\frac {- b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4\alpha c}}{2\alpha}$

We can solve $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0}\frac {- b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4\alpha c}}{2\alpha}$ with L'Hopital.

$\lim \frac {- b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4\alpha c}}{2\alpha}= \frac{\mp 2c\frac 1{\sqrt{b^2 - 4\alpha c}}}{2}=\mp \frac c{|b|} = \mp \frac c{\pm b} = - \frac cb$

Okay.... so what happens to the "other" root?

For sake of argument let's assume $b > 0$. Then one of th the two roots is$\frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  As $a$ "gets small" $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ gets close to $b$ and this expression gets close to $0/0$ so we can use L'Hopital to get that the limit. So that was the answer we got above.

But the other root is $\frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  As $s$ "gets small" $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ gets close to $b$ and this expression gets close to $-2b/0$ which diverges to negative infinity.

So.. one root converges to $-\frac cb$ and the other diverges to negative infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If $b=0$, then the roots are (if real), $\pm\sqrt{-c/a}$. If $c\ne0$, both roots tend to infinity (positive and negative).

If $b\ne0$, it's not restrictive to assume $b>0$ (otherwise multiply by $-1$).

If $c=0$, the roots are $0$ and $-b/a$, the latter tending to infinity ($\infty$ if $a$ approaches $0$ from the negative side, $-\infty$ if $a$ approaches $0$ from the positive side).

Assume $c\ne0$. The discriminant will be positive when $a$ belongs to a suitable (punctured) neighborhood of $0$, namely for $0<|a|<b^2/|4c|$, so we have two roots.

Now we can rationalize the expression for the roots.

First root:
$$
\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=
\frac{b^2-b^2+4ac}{2a(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}=
-\frac{2c}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}+b}
$$
For $a\to0$ this has limit $-c/b$. This is to be expected, because the polynomial will become $bx+c$ for $a=0$.

Second root:
$$
\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=
\frac{b^2-b^2+4ac}{2a(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac})}=
\frac{2c}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}-b}
$$
If $a\to0$, then this has limit $\pm\infty$ (according to the sign of $c$).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that my last question (in the intention of a 'slightly' different issue) accidentally can be helpful. It contains alternative expressions for the roots of the quadratic equation and their behavior for different ($\mathbb{R}$) coefficients.
[Really universal quartic formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861504/really-universal-quartic-formula) (Do not be afraid of the 'quartic' - there is more meaningful content about quadratic.)

I will present the reasoning for $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients, postponing their checking and possible generalization for the $\mathbb{C}$ ones.

We know that in the case of a ***quadratic*** equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, there are two alternative formulas for (both) roots:
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}$$
and
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
The second one can be obtained from the first by expanding the fraction with an complementary expression to the difference of squares.
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}\cdot \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}=\frac{2c}{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
or also by using of the product Vieta formula.
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}\cdot x'_{ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
1 \end{array}
}=\frac{c}{a}$$ 
$$x'_{ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
1 \end{array}
}=\frac{c}{a}\cdot \frac{2a}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
 (In the second method, the formulas for both roots were found in the reverse order, but it does not matter.)

The first one works well $\forall b,c$ and $\forall a\neq 0$, the second one $\forall a,b$ but $\forall c\neq 0$.

In the first case, you can also proceed by calculating the appropriate limits. Then one of the roots will go to infinity, and the other will go smoothly into the only element of the obtained linear equation.
$$x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & -\frac{c}{b} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & \infty \left[-\sqrt{-{\mathrm{sgn} c\ }\ }\right] \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\infty  \end{array}
\right.$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & \infty  \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & \infty \left[\sqrt{-{\mathrm{sgn} c\ }\ }\right] \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\frac{c}{b} \end{array}
\right.$$

Wherein, only finite results make sense as solutions to the linear equation!

Which root of the quadratic equation will go into the root of the linear equation depends on the sign of the linear coefficient $b$.

Formula 
$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$ 
reproduces these results without the use of limits, but it itself requires moving to the limit when $c\ =\ 0$.
$$x_1=\frac{2c}{-b+\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{c\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & -\frac{b}{a} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & 0 \end{array}
\right.$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{c\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\frac{b}{a} \end{array}
\right.$$ 
Here all the results have meaning.

That which root of the quadratic equation will go to $0$ and which in a potentially non-zero root of the obtained equation depends on the sign of the linear coefficient $b$.

There is also the possibility of refining formulas so that the root that can be calculated directly (without the use of limits) is always transformed into the root of the obtained equation.
$$x_1=\frac{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}={{\left|c=0\right|}}=-\frac{b}{a}$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}={{\left|a=0\right|=}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b\neq 0: & -\frac{c}{b} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & ? \end{array}
\right.$$ 
Of course, only the case $b\ \neq \ 0$ have meaning.

The most universal (?) set of quadratic formulas is then:
$$x_1=\frac{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$
and they work for all $\mathbb{R}$ values of coefficients. (I leave the generalization for $\mathbb{C}$ numbers for later.)