# Really universal quartic formula

Tags: quadratics, quartics

At the outset, I would like to say hello to the honorable discussants in this forum.

[This is my first entry in this forum, so I apologize in advance for any possible mess.]

I have a need to write formulas for the roots of the ***quartic*** equation $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$ so that they work $\forall a,b,c,d,e\in \mathbb{C}$ including $0$ (at least for the first and last one: $a$ and $e$). This is not about the algorithm of finding roots but about a closed formula, because what I have to examine is the behavior of individual roots of a complex quartic expression when the coefficients vary. (Besides, I want to protect the obtained expressions against numerical instability, e.g. at small values of any coefficient.)

I will present the reasoning for $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients, postponing their checking and possible generalization for the $\mathbb{C}$ ones.

We know that in the case of a ***quadratic*** equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, there are two alternative formulas for (both) roots:
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}$$
and
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
The second one can be obtained from the first by expanding the fraction with an complementary expression to the difference of squares.
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}\cdot \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}=\frac{2c}{-b\pm \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
or also by using of the product Vieta formula.
$$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}\cdot x'_{ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
1 \end{array}
}=\frac{c}{a}$$ 
$$x'_{ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 
1 \end{array}
}=\frac{c}{a}\cdot \frac{2a}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$ 
 (In the second method, the formulas for both roots were found in the reverse order, but it does not matter.)

The first one works well $\forall b,c$ and $\forall a\neq 0$, the second one $\forall a,b$ but $\forall c\neq 0$.

In the first case, you can also proceed by calculating the appropriate limits. Then one of the roots will go to infinity, and the other will go smoothly into the only root of the obtained linear equation.
$$x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & -\frac{c}{b} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & \infty \left[-\sqrt{-{\mathrm{sgn} c\ }\ }\right] \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\infty  \end{array}
\right.$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & \infty  \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & \infty \left[\sqrt{-{\mathrm{sgn} c\ }\ }\right] \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\frac{c}{b} \end{array}
\right.$$

Wherein, only finite results make sense as solutions to the linear equation!

Which root of the quadratic equation will go into the root of the linear equation depends on the sign of the linear coefficient $b$.

Formula 
$x_{ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 
2 \end{array}
}=\frac{2c}{-b\mp \sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$ 
reproduces these results without the use of limits, but it itself requires moving to the limit when $c\ =\ 0$.
$$x_1=\frac{2c}{-b+\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{c\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & -\frac{b}{a} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & 0 \end{array}
\right.$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{{\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{c\to 0}}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b<0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & 0 \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b>0: & -\frac{b}{a} \end{array}
\right.$$ 
Here all the results have meaning.

That which root of the quadratic equation will go to $0$ and which in a potentially non-zero root of the obtained equation depends on the sign of the linear coefficient $b$.

There is also the possibility of refining formulas so that the root that can be calculated directly (without the use of limits) is always transformed into the root of the obtained equation.
$$x_1=\frac{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}={{\left|c=0\right|}}=-\frac{b}{a}$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}={{\left|a=0\right|=}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{for}\ b\neq 0: & -\frac{c}{b} \\ 
\mathrm{for}\ b=0: & ? \end{array}
\right.$$ 
Of course, only the case $b\ \neq \ 0$ have meaning.

The most universal (?) set of quadratic formulas is then:
$$x_1=\frac{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}{2a}$$ 
$$x_2=\frac{2c}{-b-{\mathrm{sgn} b\ }\sqrt{\mathrm{\Delta }}}$$
and they work for all $\mathbb{R}$ values of coefficients. (I leave the generalization for $\mathbb{C}$ numbers for later.)

And now the **question** is:

Is it possible to apply a similar trick to the ***quartic*** equation? That is, to develop the formula for roots that will behave well when the first or last (or both) coefficients ($a$, $e$) will pass through $0$.

I will be grateful for the answer (preferably with justification ;) ) and also possible development of the topic and indication of sources to read.

Comment: Comment after a quick read. Your formulas for the roots of a quadratic do work formally when one of $a$ or $c$ us $0$. But in a computer program you may still face problems of numerical instability when one of those is near $0$. You will also need an if-then-else construct to calculate the sign of $b$. You could use that to detect the possible $0$ coefficients instead (all up to numerical precision ...).

Comment: The quartic can be solved exactly, but the formulas are quite messy. In practice, usually numerical methods are used. In fact, $4$ is the largest degree where an exact solution is possible in general. It is well known, that degree $5$ or higher cannot be generally solved. (Just a remark - might not be anything new for you)

Comment: There are exact solutions for degree 5, just not as radicals.  In any event yes, usually numerical methods are used above degree 2.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as Yves Daoust said before, of course, the general quartic equation formula (specifically Ferrari's method) is derived from the monic depressed quartic that is yielded from the original quartic. See this link for more details. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

To answer your question, to be able to use `a` and `e` as parameters to find roots for the equation *can* work, but unlike a quadratic equation, which only has one other term, the quartic equation will require a lot more work to find a root through such a method.

To further elaborate, in a quadratic equation of form `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`, you just need to the roots that match the middle to `bx`. However, a general quartic is of the form `ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0`, so you would have to match `bx^3`, `cx^2`, and `dx`. Of course, your proposed method can definitely work for biquadratic equations, i.e. `ax^4 + cx^2 + e = 0`, but unfortunately, even Ferrari's solution requires the use of two plus-and-minus signs, and using the general formula to create such forms for your quartic solutions is possible, but perhaps even more cluttered than Ferrari's solution already is.

FYI, the intermediate values seen in Ferrari's solution are there for ease of readability and calculation. They are not absolutely necessary but if they are not used, they will make the formula **extremely** cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

The general [quartic roots formulas](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be%3D0) are tremendous. I am not sure that anyone completely tackled the numerical stability issues for such monsters.

When these formulas are used, this is in general through the use of intermediate parameters. In particular, the polynomial is first made monic (so that $a=0$ is excluded), then depressed. I don't even know if using stable expressions for these parameters can improve the global stability.

Comment: These expressions are long but not so terrible, because each of the 4 solutions consist of 4 common blocks, simply connected with the use of a plus or minus depending on which solution we are considering. I will justify why I care for analytic regular closed formulas and not for numerical procedures. In the specific case on which I work, the final expression will be simplified thanks to certain symmetries, which, however, do not help in solving the equation. I need analytical formulas because I count (not without reason) that in further calculations much will be simplified.

Comment: Regular behavior of solutions with variable parameter values would be very desirable. Such a solution gives a better insight into the physical (and, in fact, geometric) meaning of results, because in fact irregular behavior of the results in the limit $a \rightarrow 0$ is only an apparent singularity. That's why I'm looking for formulas that do not show a disguise of singularity. Besides what interests me, for everyone a more universal formula should be valuable. For a _**quadratic**_ equation they were found. The question is whether it is possible for _**quartic**_.

Comment: I said that the singularities are only apparent. In my case there are phenomena such as smooth transition of one solution into another or exchange of poles from the inside and outside of the integration contour. (That's why I need the zeroes of a certain polynomial in the denominator of integrand.) Ultimately, everything is smooth.